# Function that works like a `sentence` function except that it works with lists

Tags: list, scheme, flatten

So I am trying to figure out how to write `sentence-helper` so the `new-sentence` function works like the `sentence` function in Simply Scheme.

Here is what it is supposed to look like:

```
> (new-sentence '())
  '()
> (new-sentence 'a '(b) '(((c)) d e))
  '(a b c d e)
```

This is what I am given:

```
(define (new-sentence . inputs)
  (sentence-helper inputs))

(define (sentence-helper lyst)

  (cond ((________ lyst) ________)

        ((________ (________ lyst))

         (________ (sentence-helper (________ lyst))

                   (sentence-helper (________ lyst))))

        (else (________ (________ lyst)

                        (sentence-helper (________ lyst))))))
```

How do you suggest I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you solve the assignment by doing simple input to expected output.
I'm guessing I would have chosen:

```
(new-sentences)
(new-sentences '(a) 'b)
(new-sentences 'a 'b)
```

And they should become:

```
(sentence-helper '())
(sentence-helper '((a) b))
(sentence-helper '(a b))
```

And off the bat the first one should become `()` and is definitive your base case. The other two are cases is when the firt element is a `pair?` since then you need to recurse both the element and the rest of the list. You'll get `(a)` and `(b)` but are after `(a b)` as result. Te last example should just cons each element to the resursion of the rest. When you think you are done you should some more complex examples:

```
(new-sentences '((a b)) 'c 'd) 
; ==> (a b c d)
(new-sentences '(a b) '(c d)) 
; ==> (a b c d)
(new-sentences 'a 'b '(c d)) 
; ==> (a b c d)
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd invoke [John McCarthy's `gopher`](https://www.dreamsongs.com/10ideas.html) on them (those that gave you this assignment) and go

```
(define (new-sentence . inputs)
  (sentence-helper inputs))

(define (sentence-helper lyst)

  (cond ((___null___ lyst) ___'()___)

        ((___pair?___ (___c_r___ lyst))

         (___(lambda (a b) ; rotate to the right, kind of
               (new-sentence (c_r a) (c_r a) b)
               )_____ 

                   (sentence-helper (___c_r___ lyst))

                   (sentence-helper (___c_r___ lyst))))

        (else (____cons____ (____c_r____ lyst)

                        (sentence-helper (____c_r____ lyst))))))
```

You still need to complete the function names there, to decide where the `car` or the `cdr` are appropriate.

Of course using that `lambda` there is likely not allowed, but it could be nice to work this thing out, when you're learning the language.